# Finding source of father's first name on 1713 Staffordshire baptism from FamilySearch index?

Tags: england, 18th-century, baptism-records, staffordshire

William Fletcher, who I believe to have been my 6th great grandfather was baptised on 27 Sep 1713 at St Mary, Brewood, Staffordshire, England.

The image of that baptism, from FindMyPast's [Staffordshire baptisms](https://search.findmypast.co.uk/record?id=gbprs%2Fstaff%2Fbap2%2F027805) (Archive Reference D4014/1/3 Page 40), appears below, and to me it can be seen quite clearly that the christian name of his father has been omitted:

[image]

However, [FindMyPast presents an England, Births & Baptisms 1538-1975 Transcription](https://search.findmypast.co.uk/record?id=r_939551629) (presumably based on FamilySearch information) which says:

```
Father's first name(s)  Jo
Father's last name  Fletcher
```

Ancestry.com's England, Select Births and Christenings, 1538-1975 (based on England, Births and Christenings, 1538-1975. Salt Lake City, Utah: FamilySearch, 2013.) says:

```
Father  Jo Fletcher
```

and FamilySearch says:

```
Father's Name   Jo Fletcher
```

> "England Births and Christenings, 1538-1975," database, FamilySearch
>   (https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:J3M7-DM6 : 6 December 2014,
>   William Fletcher, 27 Sep 1713); citing SAINT
>   MARY,BREWOOD,STAFFORD,ENGLAND, index based upon data collected by the
>   Genealogical Society of Utah, Salt Lake City; FHL microfilm 417,174.

Is there another image, or paper record, that these three websites (all citing the same *[England Births and Christenings, 1538-1975](https://www.familysearch.org/search/collection/1473014?collectionNameFilter=false)* database) could have been trusting as their source to transcribe William's father's name as Jo?

I note that a father named John appears a few rows down suggesting that the writer of these records did not abbreviate that name to "Jo".

Comment: Do you know if the image is from the original register or the Bishop's Transcript?

Comment: @sempaiscuba That's a good question and reminds me that it is something that I need to check, and from https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/12799/determining-if-findmypast-image-comes-from-parish-register-bishops-transcript I should know how to.

Comment: The [film number](https://www.familysearch.org/search/catalog/results?count=20&query=%2Bfilm_number%3A417174) quoted for the FamilySearch record is for the Bishop's Transcript, rather than the original register.

Comment: I'm looking for Archive Reference D4014/1/3 at http://www.archives.staffordshire.gov.uk/CalmView/advanced.aspx?src=CalmView.Catalog now but have not yet succeeded in finding it.  It is a new site to me.

Comment: @sempaiscuba On page 170 0f 440 at https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/3:1:3Q9M-CS62-1Z98?i=169&cat=319957 it looks like it says Jo.  I hope you are able to write an answer that includes that information since you lead me to it.

Comment: Please clarify this. You say "all citing the same England, Select Births and Christenings, 1538-1975 database" but that can't be.  The "select" births and christenings title is Ancestry's re-titling of the FamilySearch database.  Please make it more clear exactly what Ancestry and findmypast are citing.  The same batch number, the same FHL film, and/or the name of the database *as it appears on FamilySearch* since FamilySearch is where this is all coming from.  The register is the original, FamilySearch is copy #1, and Ancestry & fmp have copied copy #1. This is not 3 independent sites.

Comment: Foolish to be dogmatic, but I have never seen John abbreviated to Jo (actually Jo:). I suspect but wouldn't like to put money on it, that it should read Jos: - in other words, Joseph. Wonder if that's why the name got omitted from the final copy of the Parish Register? The (presumed) rough copy had Jo: which got copied onto the BT and when the time came to write up the PR, the clerk said, "What's that?" and, not understanding, left it out. All speculation.

Comment: @JanMurphy I'm hoping that I have now made the records that I consulted a little clearer, and am always happy if anyone is keen to make them clearer still.

Comment: @AdrianB38 I'm glad you mentioned Jo probably being Jos/Joseph because I think every time I see either Jo or Jno I have been assuming John.  For Jno I hope John is correct:-)

Comment: Jno or Jno: - perhaps with optional superscription - is always John so far 
as I know. Hardly seems worth the abbreviation!

Comment: I have corrected the reference to the FamilySearch database at the end of your question where you were calling it by the title Ancestry uses, and have added the link to the database at FamilySearch.  Note that it is index only. https://www.familysearch.org/search/collection/1473014  See also the Wiki article about this collection at https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/England_Births_and_Christenings_(FamilySearch_Historical_Records)

Comment: In the spirit of "write the title last" I've made another edit to the title. Trying to get it to be shorter, and something that is more likely to turn up in a search.

Comment: @JanMurphy improving question titles is something I strongly support

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's always worth double-checking to see whether the online image comes from the original register or the [Bishop's Transcripts](https://blog.findmypast.com/to-every-book-its-copy-parish-records-and-bishops-transcripts-1406088135.html).

I've certainly sometimes found that the transcriptions on sites like FindMyPast don't always quite match the images available on the site. Sometimes this is just an error in transcription, but on other occasions it has been because the transcription seems to have been made from the original register while the available image shows the Bishop's Transcripts (or vice versa).

---

In this case, the [film number](https://www.familysearch.org/search/catalog/results?count=20&query=%2Bfilm_number%3A417174) quoted for the FamilySearch record is for the Bishop's Transcript, rather than the original register for Brewood.

As you found, checking the [image](https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/3:1:3Q9M-CS62-1Z98?cat=319957) on FamilySearch on this occasion does indeed show William's father as Jo Fletcher:

[image: Fletcher]

---

This isn't the first time that I have seen several sites in agreement over a transcription of a record where that transcription doesn't match the available image on some of those sites. Personally, it does make me wonder how much of the transcribed information available on the various search sites has been "shared" in some form or other.

These days, where I can I always try to check both the original images from both the parish registers and the Bishop's Transcripts. Sometimes there is just that one extra nugget of useful information ... :)

Staffordshire Archives have a useful [guide](https://www.staffordshire.gov.uk/leisure/archives/services/publications/ParishRegisterGuide2015July-v3.pdf) to their holdings of parish registers and Bishop's Transcripts.

Comment: I think it is a mistake to categorize this situation as "several sites in agreement" when we have a clear case of two sites sharing the same database with a third site.  If Ancestry and findmypast are both citing the same collection on FamilySearch, this is three copies of one site, not three independent sets of indexers all arriving at the same thing.

Comment: @JanMurphy Hence my point about "shared" transcriptions, although I've found that the citation isn't always as clear as it is in this case. The point is that the transcription doesn't always match the images on a particular site.